# Issue with angular module federation version 16

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I have upgraded my remote api to version 16 for angular and angular module federation facing below issue:

error stack

[image]

Webpackconfig.js

[image]

bootstrap.ts

[image]

I added following lines to main.ts

```
import('./bootstrap').catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

but nothing is working for me. Its plain angular non NX project